# How to use spring properties in gradle.build?

Tags: gradle

How can I use properties configured in resources/application.properties in gradle.build? I would like to get something like this :

```
flyway {
    url = MAP_WITH_PROPERTIES['spring.datasource.url']
    user = MAP_WITH_PROPERTIES['spring.datasource.username']
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import java.util.Properties
def props = new Properties()
file('src/main/resources/application.properties').withInputStream {
   props.load(it)
}
def url = props['spring.datasource.url']
def user = props['spring.datasource.username']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load properties and use them this way:

```
ext.ApplicationProps = new Properties()
ApplicationProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"))
```

And use it as follows:

```
flyway {
    url = ApplicationProps['spring.datasource.url']
    user = ApplicationProps['spring.datasource.username']
}
```

Just note, that path to the properties is defined from the root and may vary if you have a multimodule project.

Comment: `new FileInputStream("src/main/...")` may not work in a multi-module build. I suggest making use of the `file(...)` method for proper path resolution.

Comment: @LanceJava yes, the File is better for such a case, I had never thought about it, +1 for your note